Depiction of Surya and other Navagrahas
So you know how sometimes you see a drawing of the sun with a face on it or another planet etc. Well is there any ancient depiction of the face of the Deva on the Graha?

Depiction of any deity is part of their Dhyana Shlokas.
Depiction of the Navagrahas, in particular, can be found in Matsya Purana (Matsya Purana, Chapter 94, Verse 1-9). Quoting from the book "Essence of Maysya Purana":


12    Features of ‘Nava Grahas’ and Procedure of Navagraha Shanti
Adithyaya Somaaya Mangalaaya Budhaayacha  Guru Shukra
Sanirbhyascha Rahavey Ketavey Namah/
Surya, Chandra, Mangala, Budha, Brihaspati, Shukra, Shani, Rahu and
Keta are all expected to be basically benificient ‘Grahas’ (Planets).
Description of their ‘Swarupas’ (Forms) is as follows:
Padmaasanah Padmakarah Padmagarbha samuddhitah, Saptaashvah
Saptarujjuscha Dwibhujah syaat sadaa Ravih/
(Surya Deva has two hands wearing two lotuses, seated on a lotus
flower; his luster is abundant like that of the outside part of a
lotus; Surya Deva is comfortably seated on a magnificent chariot
driven by Seven Horses).
Swetah Swetaambaradharah Swetaashvah Swetavaahanah
Gadaapaanirdwibaahus cha Kartavyo varadah Shashee
(Chandra Deva is of white colour, wears white clothes, has white
horses, white chariot, with ‘gada’/ mace and ‘Varada Mudra’ or sign of
Protection).
Raktamaalyaambara dharah Shakti Shula Gadadharah, Chaturbhujah
Raktaromaa varadah syad Dharaasutah/
(Dhrarani nandana or the son of Earth, Mangala is adorned with Shakti,
Trishula, Gada and Vara Mudra on his four hands; his body colour is
blood red, wears red clothes and red flower garland)
Peetamaalyaambara dharah Karnikaa –rasamadyutih, Khadgacharma
gadaa paanih Simhastho varado Budhah/
(Budha Deva wears yellow flower garland and yellow clothes with body
colour too yellowish; he sports a sword, shield, mace and ‘Vara mudra’
by his four hands and is seated on a lion);
Deva daitya Guru Taddhat peetaswaitow chaturbhujaow, Dandinow
Varadow Kaaryao Saakshasutra Kamandalu/
(The ‘Pratimas’ or Idols of Deva Guru Brihaspati and of Danava Guru
Shukraachaarya should respectively be of yellow and white colours;
their hands are ornamented with Danda, Rudrakshamaala, Kamandalu and
Varada Mudra).
Indra neela dutih Shuli varado Grudhra vaahanah Baana
baanaasanadharah kartavy -orka suthastathaa/
(Shanaischara’s body colour is of ‘Indraneelamani’ / blue diamond; he
rides a ‘Grudhra’ / Vulture and carries bow and arrows, Trishula and
Varada Mudra).
Karaala vadanah Khadgacharma Shuli Varapradah, Neela
simhaasanascha Rahuratra Prashasyatey/
( Rahu Deva is fierce looking, carries sword, skin sheath, Shula and
Vara Prada by his four hands and is seated on a blue throne).
Dhumraa Dwibaahavah Sarvey Gadino vikrutaananah, Grudhraasana
gataa nithyam Ketavah Syurvara pradaah/
(Ketu Deva is of grey colour and of fierce Rupa with two hands showing
gadaa and varada mudra seated always on a vulture)
Sarvey kireetinah kaaryaa Grahaa Lokahitaavahaah,
Hyaanguleynocchritaah Sarvey shatamashtottaram sadaa/
(These are all beneficient Grahas worthy of ornamentation with
‘Kiritas’/head gears and be of hundred eight inches of Pratimas /
Idols).

Next the Purana continues to describe how the ritualistic worship of these Grahas should be performed.

It's a good answer, but I want a unique description as stated above where some of the features of deva are incorporated into the spherical graha form
